# How to generate vue component in body?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to create a popup component that will be placed at the end of the body.

I saw this in vuetify, but due to the complexity of the structure, I couldn't find in the source code which function put this element there.

It is necessary that the component be placed at the bottom of the body when created, and removed when unmounted. At the same time, so that you can receive emits from it and pass parameters

[example with vuetify](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vuetify-example-t9g9kt?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltognry400072067gteby1zs%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltognry400022067cjv7yo6p%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltognry400042067nynl8vxy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltognry400062067hbg2kh8r%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltognry400022067cjv7yo6p%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltognry400022067cjv7yo6p%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522cltognry400062067hbg2kh8r%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltognry400052067jb8lgz95%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522pnpm%2520run%2520dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltognry400062067hbg2kh8r%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltognry400052067jb8lgz95%2522%257D%252C%2522cltognry400042067nynl8vxy%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltognry400042067nynl8vxy%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltognry4000320675g27u3o6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522pnpm%2520run%2520dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltognry4000320675g27u3o6%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: Have you read the docs for [vue teleport](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html)?

Comment: @dbzx10299 Yes, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm searching for function, not component

Comment: @Relow This is how it works in vue, this is literally what the guide describes https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/teleport.html#basic-usage . You change v-if condition with a function. Use global store to interact with a modal through the app

Answer (score 0):

Check out [v-snackbar](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/snackbars/?version=v2.7.1#usage) in vuetify. That might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(div);
Vue.createApp(componentDefinition).mount(div)
```

Please note you've asked a [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Most likely, if you asked about how to fix the problem you're trying to fix by placing a component at the end of `<body />` I would have given you a more useful answer, solving the actual problem.

---

Here's how a `<Teleport />` implementation would look like:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const app = createApp({
  setup: () => ({
    open: ref(false),
    foo: ref('bar')
  })
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.modal-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.42);
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 9px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07),0 3px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.06)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.prod.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="foo" /><br />
  <pre>{{ { foo } }}</pre>
  <button @click="open = true">Open Modal</button>
  
  <Teleport to="body">
    <div v-if="open" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-backdrop" @click="open = false"></div>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Hello from the modal!</p>
        <input v-model="foo" />
        <pre>{{ { foo } }}</pre>
        <button @click="open = false">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Teleport>
</div>
```

As can be observed, although the modal is teleported to `body`, it still has access to the test model of `foo`. In fact, from Vue's perspective, the modal is still a child node of App, so if there were any props involved, everything would work disregarding the fact that the actual DOM element is rendered elsewhere.